# Remotely changing hard drive boot order, windows 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, multi-boot, remote-access

I have one workstation chassis with two hard drives.  Depending on which one I boot from, I get one of two different operating systems: both are windows 7, but they have different static IPs, serve totally different purposes, etc.    The workstation has a modern asus motherboard, core i7 intel CPU, 32 GB ram.

Is there a way to remotely change which hard drive is booted from on a reboot?  Both systems have remote users, and i'd like a solution that is more elegant than being physically present and selecting boot order manually.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do this unfortunately unless you are on a HP windows machine as far as I know.

You can have a look into this if you do have a HP device: 
http://www8.hp.com/us/en/ads/clientmanagement/drivers-bios.html

However a more elegant solution to your problem would be to look into raid0 and virtualisation for your workstation. With raid0 you can combine your two hard drives into one volume. Then with virtualisation software such as VMWare you could host two virtual windows machines at the same time. If you want only one of these to be available, you could remotely administrate this using remote desktop to sign in and switch between the virtual machines.

The downside to this is that you would lose a small percentage of machine resources as you would be effectively running windows on windows, but it should be minimal.

Comment: Both workstations are doing very GPU-heavy work.  I don't believe virtualization is in my best interests in this case.

Comment: I won't be able to help you further then, I don't think what you are asking is possible, sorry.

Comment: You could always try to install VMWare on one of the hard drives beforehand and do a benchmark to test. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check [RealVNC](https://www.realvnc.com/) remote access, you can reboot the machine then send [F8](https://www.realvnc.com/products/vnc/documentation/5.0/guides/user/af1059839.html) or F12 command to view the boot menu options.

Answer (score 0):

There actually is a way to change the UEFI boot order while e.g. logged in via RDP. I just tested this with the trial version of [EasyUEFI](https://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) on Windows 10 and changed the boot order successfully from my Windows drive to my Ubuntu drive.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but since you have the i7 you can try Out-Of-Band Management. Just make sure your chipset is vpro. Take a look at the Intel sticker on the front of the chassis.

Comment: What is this?  How does it work?  Can you provide a reference? … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.